# Detect if a SKSpriteNode left the screen at the bottom and call a function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have tried to find a way to **detect** if a **SKSpriteNode** **left** **the** **screen** (I would like to call a Game Over function).

I have declared the node within a function (It is not global if I get that right?) and made and SKAction that moves the Node out of the screen and removes it afterwards.

This is what I came up with:

```
 var node = SKSpriteNode()

 let nodeTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "node")
 nodeTexture.filteringMode = .Nearest
 node = SKSpriteNode(texture: nodeTexture)

 let nodeFalling = SKAction.moveToY(-70, duration: 1.6)
 let nodeRemoving = SKAction.removeFromParent()
 node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([nodeFalling, nodeRemoving]))

 self.addChild(node)
```

Now what I need is to call GameOver() if the node left the screen.

I am very thankful for every answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scene you have to remember the reference for node you want to check and then in `update` method you just do the following:

```
    if node.position.y < -node.size.height/2.0 {
            node.removeFromParent()
            gameOver()

    }
```

Edit:

```
class MyScene: SKScene {
// ....

//here is the list of nodes which you want to check
var nodesToCheck = [SKSpriteNode]()

//here is your spawn function

func spawnNewNode() {
    var node = SKSpriteNode()

    let nodeTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "node")
    nodeTexture.filteringMode = .Nearest
    node = SKSpriteNode(texture: nodeTexture)

    let nodeFalling = SKAction.moveToY(-70, duration: 1.6)
    let nodeRemoving = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([nodeFalling, nodeRemoving]))

    self.addChild(node)
    nodesToCheck.append(node)
}

//and here is the update method

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    super.update(currentTime)

    // ... every other update logic

    for node in nodesToCheck {
        if node.position.y < -node.size.height/2.0 {
            node.removeFromParent()
            gameOver()
        }
    }
}

func gameOver() {
    println("Damn!")
}

}
```

Dont forget to remove your node from `nodeToCheck` array when they are no longer scene members.

Comment: I am spawning multiple nodes using a timer in another function. Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "remembering the reference for the node" in my scene. I would highly appreciate if you could give me an example for that @s1ddok . Thanks Anyway!!!

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me really much!! Am I right that I need to implement this action `node.removeChildrenInArray(nodesToCheck)`? You did already so much work, I am completely fine if you do not answer this. @s1ddok

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: To make it clear, I would like to know what you mean by removing the node from node to check.

Comment: When your node is removed by other logic instead of reaching the bottom of the screen, you should also remove it from this array, so It wont affect gameover condition anymore.

Comment: As soon as 1 cat leaves the screen I get endless ns logs that the gameOver func is called, Is there a way that this does not happen?

Comment: Well, in you gameOver method you should pause the scene and handle the gameover logic.